# Crystal Reports book for formulas or charts

Tags: crystal-reports

I have completed Crystal Reports 2011 for developers  and  i am ready to move onto the next stage
I would like to learn ways of doing complicated reports ( as that is my job now ). 
Is there a good advanced or intermediate book out there on formulas 
and one on charts , these are the two areas i wish to develop
any help would be appreciated

Thank you so much

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in charge of all metrics reporting where I work. I write and maintain all of our Crystal Reports. Here are two books you should look at.

1. Crystal Reports XI: The Complete Reference (Osborne Complete Reference Series)
2. No Stress Tech Guide To Crystal Reports XI For Beginners (2nd Edition)

Both of these books have good sections on formulas. The second book has a pretty good section on Charts. The rest of it might be a little basic for you, but it's a fairly good reference book.

Both can be found on Amazon.com

If you want to get even deeper on the formulas, learn visual basic. Just search visual basic for crystal reports and you'll find a wealth of resources.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so so much for your help, will try get the complete reference